# Postgres use index with `split_part`

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, split, jsonb

**Context:**

I have a `test` table:

```
=> \d+ test 
                                       Table "public.test"
Column     |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
---------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------- 
------+-------------
 id            | character varying(255) |           |          |         | extended |              
| 
 configuration | jsonb                  |           |          |         | extended |              
|
```

The `configuration` column contains "well-defined" json, which has a key called `source_url` (Skipping other non-relevant keys). An example value for `configuration` column is:

```
{
"source_url": "https://<resource-address>?Signature=R1UzTGphWEhrTTFFZnc0Q4qkGRxkA5%2BHFZSfx3vNEvRsrlDcHdntArfHwkWiT7Qxi%2BWVJ4DbHJeFp3GpbS%2Bcb1H3r1PXPkfKB7Fjr6tFRCetDWAOtwrDrVOkR9G1m7iOePdi1RW%2Fn1LKE7MzQUImpkcZXkpHTUgzXpE3TPgoeVtVOXXt3qQBARpdSixzDU8dW%2FcftEkMDVuj4B%2Bwiecf6st21MjBPjzD4GNVA%2F6bgvKA6ExrdYmM5S6TYm1lz2e6juk81%2Fk4eDecUtjfOj9ekZiGJVMyrD5Tyw%2FTWOrfUB2VM1uw1PFT2Gqet87jNRDAtiIrJiw1lfB7Od1AwNxIk0Rqkrju8jWxmQhvb1BJLV%2BoRH56OHdm5nHXFmQdldVpyagQ8bQXoKmYmZPuxQb6t9FAyovGMav3aMsxWqIuKTxLzjB89XmgwBTxZSv5E9bkWUbom2%2BWq4O3%2BCrVxYwsqg%3D%3D&Expires-At=1569340020&Issued-At=1568293200"
    .
    .
}
```

The URL contains a query param `Expires-At`

---

**Problem:**

There is a scheduled job that runs every 24 hours. This job should find all such records which are expired/about to expire(and then do something about it).

**Solution:**

I have this query to get my job done:

```
select * from test where to_timestamp(split_part(split_part(configuration->>'source_url', 'Expires-At=', 2), '&', 1)::bigint) <= now() + interval '24 hours';
```

**Explanation:**

- The query first splits the `source_url` at `Expires-At=` and picks the part present at the right of it and then it splits the resultant string on `&` and picks the left part of it, thus getting the exact epoch time needed as `text`
- The same query also works for the corner case when `Expires-At` is the last query param in the `source_url`
- Once it extracts the epoch time as `text`, it first converts it to a `bigint` and then convert it to Postgres timestamp and then this timestamp is compared if it is going to be less than or equal to the time 24 hours away from `now()`
- All rows passing the above condition are selected

So, at the end, in each run, scheduler refreshes all the urls that will expire in the next 24 hours (including the ones, which are already expired)

---

**Questions:**

1. Though this solves my problem, I really don't like this solution. This has a lot of string manipulation which I kind of find as un-clean. Is there a much cleaner way to do this?
2. If we "have" to go with above solution, can we even use indices for this kind of query? I know the functions `lower()`, `upper()` extra can be indexed, but I really can't think of any way where I could index this query.

**Alternatives:**

Unless there is a real clean solution, I am going to go with this:

- I would introduce a new key inside `configuration` json called `expires_at`, making sure, this gets filled with the correct value, every time a row is inserted.
- And then directly query this newly added field(have the index on `configuration` column).

I admit that this way I am repeating the information `Expires-At`, but out of all possible solution I could think of, this is the one which I find to be most clean.

Is there a better way than this that you folks can think of?

---

---

**EDIT:**

Updated the query to use `substring()` with regex instead of inner `split_part()`:

```
select * from test where to_timestamp(split_part(substring(configuration->>'source_url' from 'Expires-At=\d+'), '=', 2)::bigint) <= now() + interval '24 hours';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your current data model, I don't find your `WHERE` condition that bad.

You can index it with

```
CREATE INDEX ON test ( 
   to_timestamp(
      split_part(
         split_part(
            configuration->>'source_url',
            'Expires-At=',
            2
         ),
         '&',
         1
      )::bigint
   )
);
```

Essentially, youbhave to index the whole expression on the left side of `=`. You can only do that if all functions and operators involved are `IMMUTABLE`, which I think they are in your case.

I would change the data model though. First, I don't see the value of having a `jsonb` column with a single value in it. Why not have the URL as a `text` column instead?

You could go farther and split the URL into individual parts which are stored in columns.

If all this is a good idea depends on how you use the value in the database: often it is a good idea to split off those parts of the data that you use in `WHERE` conditions and the like and leave the rest "in a lump". This is to some extent a matter of taste.

Comment: I have skipped other keys from the `jsonb` column for brevity. It contains 2 more keys, that's why it's of type `jsonb`.

Comment: Don't. `split_part` is much cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a URI parsing module, if that is the part you find unclean.  You could use plperl or plpythonu, with whatever URI parser library in them you prefer.  But if your json is really "well defined" I don't see much point.  Unless you are already using plperl or plpythonu, adding those dependencies probably adds more "dirt" than it removes.

You can build an index:

```
create index on test (to_timestamp(split_part(split_part(configuration->>'source_url', 'Expires-At=', 2), '&', 1)::bigint));
set enable_seqscan TO off;
explain select * from test where to_timestamp(split_part(split_part(configuration->>'source_url', 'Expires-At=', 2), '&', 1)::bigint) <= now() + interval '24 hours';
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using test_to_timestamp_idx1 on test  (cost=0.13..8.15 rows=1 width=36)
   Index Cond: (to_timestamp(((split_part(split_part((configuration ->> 'source_url'::text), 'Expires-At='::text, 2), '&'::text, 1))::bigint)::double precision) <= (now() + '24:00:00'::interval))
```

> I would introduce a new key inside configuration json called expires_at, making sure, this gets filled with the correct value, every time a row is inserted.

Isn't that just re-arranging the dirt?  It makes the query look nicer, at the expense of making the insert uglier.  Perhaps you could put it in an INSERT OR UPDATE trigger.